# My usort code is not working well

Tags: php

I have problem with sorting this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 120
            [registration_date] => 2012-10-19 16:57:46
            [username] => Jeff
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 121
            [registration_date] => 2012-12-23 16:57:46
            [username] => Peter
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 122
            [registration_date] => 2012-11-30 16:57:46
            [username] => Susan
        )

)
```

It is stored in variable:

```
$unsorted_users
```

I want to order this array **DESC** by **registration_date** so it looks like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 121
                [registration_date] => 2012-12-23 16:57:46
                [username] => Peter

            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 122
                [registration_date] => 2012-11-30 16:57:46
                [username] => Susan

            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 120
                [registration_date] => 2012-10-19 16:57:46
                [username] => Jeff
            )

    )
```

and it is ordered by registration_date like:

```
2012-12-23 16:57:46
2012-11-30 16:57:46
2012-10-19 16:57:46
```

Instead of original where it was like:

```
2012-10-19 16:57:46
2012-12-23 16:57:46
2012-11-30 16:57:46
```

I am using this code, but it is not working good (the print_r($sorted_users); output of $sorted_users is "1". I don't why it is 1 and not sorted array.)

```
$sorted_users = usort($unsorted_users, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['registration_date'] - $b['registration_date'];
});
```

Any advice why is my code for $sorted_users wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't substract (that) strings. If you want to compare two strings, use the strcmp() function like this:

```
<?php

//  setup
$unsorted_users = array();

$t = new stdClass(); 
$t->id = 120; $t->username = 'jeff'; $t->registration_date = '2012-10-19 16:57:46'; 
$unsorted_users[] = $t;

$t = new stdClass(); 
$t->id = 121; $t->username = 'Peter'; $t->registration_date = '2012-12-23 16:57:46'; 
$unsorted_users[] = $t;

$t = new stdClass(); 
$t->id = 122; $t->username = 'Susan'; $t->registration_date = '2012-11-30 16:57:46'; 
$unsorted_users[] = $t;
// end setup


$sorted_users =    // this var is nor relevant as it shoud be allways true
usort($unsorted_users, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp ($a->registration_date, $b->registration_date) ;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($unsorted_users)   // that is in fact ordered!

?>
```

fiddle [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rug-dxv)

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 3):

`usort` is working on the array by reference, and returning success boolean - so your `$sorted_users` is containing that boolean. The original array should now be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

There are some valid answers already, but to add to them:

Your variables are contained in an object, not an array; you have an array of objects you want to sort, so you should use:

```
$a->registration_date
// etc.
```

instead of:

```
$a['registration_date']
```

Comment: Thanks, now, with combining with Luis it is working, thanks ;)